# What is the relationship between the HJB and "Hamiltonian"? Why is the Hamiltonian H(p) inside the HJB?

Tags: optimal-control, continuous-time

Deterministic Optimal Control Problem
$
V(a_t) 
= 
\underset{c}{\max}
\int_{\tau =t}^{\tau = \infty} e^{-\rho (\tau - t) } u(c_{\tau}) d\tau
$
s.t.
$
\frac{da}{d\tau} = \left( r a_{\tau}  - c_{\tau} \right)  $

**CV Hamiltonian**:
$H^{CV} \equiv  u(c_t) + \lambda_{t} \times (r a_{t}  - c_{t})$
$H^{CV}_c=0$, $H^{CV}_a=\rho \lambda - \frac{d\lambda}{dt}$,
$H^{CV}_\lambda = \frac{da}{dt}$
Boils down to system of boundary-value DAEs.
If you can eliminate $\lambda$, system of BV-ODEs.

**HJB**:
$\rho V(a_t) = \underset{c}{\max}
\{ u(c_{t}) + V_a \times (r a_{t}  - c_{t}) \}$

Authors often define the term in the HJB which depends on the control as "Hamiltonian":
$H\left( V_a\right) \equiv 
\underset{c}{\max} \{ u(c) - c_{t} \times  V_a  \} \Rightarrow c(a_t) =u'^{-1} \left( V_a(a_t) \right)$
Hence $\Leftrightarrow \rho V(a_t) = H\left( V_a\right) + V_a \times r a_{t}$

Adrien Bilal ([p9](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vXgezoAHRCRnybN9Yis68RcLCghYW3gu/view)) and [Neil Walton](https://appliedprobability.blog/) & others, call the term inside the HJB
$H\left( V_a\right)$ a Hamiltonian.
If we set $\lambda_{t} \equiv V_a$ then $H^{CV} = H\left( V_a\right) + \lambda  \times r a_{t}$.

**Q1**: why do they add the term $H\left( V_a\right)$ inside the HJB?
-guess: it separates the non-linear part of HJB
-guess: it separates the part of the HJB that depends on the control
**Q2**: why do they call $H\left( V_a\right)$ a "hamiltonian"?

**Note**: I am NOT asking if the solution to the HJB is the same as to the Hamiltonian.
Sol to HJB: $V(a_t)$ gives policy $c(a_t) = u'^{-1}(V_a)$
Combine policy w/ transition eqn: you get $c^{HJB}(t)$
Sol to CV Hamiltonian: $c^{H}(t)$
I can show (under appropriate assumptions) that $c^{HJB}(t)=c^{H}(t)$.

(side-node) Recall: $H^{CV}_c=0$ & $H^{CV}_a=\rho \lambda - \frac{d\lambda}{dt}$
$H^{CV}_a=\rho \lambda - \frac{d\lambda}{dt}$:
implies $\lambda r = \rho \lambda - \frac{d\lambda}{dt}$
implies $V_a (\rho-r) = V_{aa} (r a_{t}  - c_{t})$

Answer (score 1):

Since you mention Walton, here is something from his notes page 111 Definition 4:

> The Hamiltonian and is defined
> $H(t,x,\rho) := min _v \{c(t,x,v) - \rho v\}$

Notice the analogue to the Hamiltonian you have written.

$v$ in here is the control (your $c$), $c(t,x,v)$ in here is the $u(c)$ function you have and $-\rho = \partial_xL(t,x)$ in here where $L$ is the minimized loss, analogous to your maximized value.

Answer to your second question: That is simply how a Hamiltonian is defined.

Answer to your first question:
When the HJB is derived it has that specific form. For example see Benjamin Moll's notes, slides 8-10.

I hope this helps.

References:

Walton:  https://appliedprobability.files.wordpress.com/2021/01/stochastic_control_jan29.pdf

Moll: https://benjaminmoll.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/Lecture3_2149.pdf